# Suitable pipe suggestion required

Tags: pipelines, waterproofing, air, tubing

I've got a machine that sucks water. The inlet is half inch. I had been using braided pvc till now but it has started to breathe air which is causing problems with the machine. It also bends under stress or in hot weather. I'd like a half inch pipe that doesn't breath and doesn't bend and can be pulled over a barbed nipple. Any ideas what I should be looking for?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=suction+hose&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a pipe rated for suction.

Or use a corrugated steel inner which won’t collapse - did that for one application…

Comment: I think that makes sense. Thanks.